# Should I use SQL JOIN or IN Clause?

Tags: sql, join

I have a question about best approach. I am not sure which approach is best when data is considered variable in size.

Consider the following 3 TABLES:

**EMPLOYEE**

EMPLOYEE_ID, EMP_NAME

**PROJECT**

PROJECT_ID, PROJ_NAME

**EMP_PROJ** (many to many of above two tables)

EMPLOYEE_ID, PROJECT_ID

**Problem**:  Given an EmployeeID,  find ALL the employees of ALL Projects that this Employee is associated with.

I have tried this in two way.. both approaches differ only by few milliseconds no matter what size of data is used.

```
SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMP_PROJ    
    WHERE PROJECT_ID IN (
        SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM EMP_PROJ p, EMPLOYEE e
        WHERE p.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID 
        AND  E.EMPLOYEE_ID = 123)
```

go

```
select c.EMP_NAME FROM
(SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM EMP_PROJ 
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 123) a
JOIN 
EMP_PROJ b
ON a.PROJECT_ID = b.PROJECT_ID
JOIN 
EMPLOYEE c
ON b.EMPLOYEE_ID = c.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

As of now, I expect around 5000 Employees and Projects each.. but have no idea about what kinda many-many relationship exists.
Which approach would u recommend?
thanks!

EDIT:
Execution Plan of Approach 1

```
"Hash Join  (cost=86.55..106.11 rows=200 width=98)"
"  Hash Cond: (employee.employee_id = emp_proj.employee_id)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on employee  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=610 width=102)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=85.07..85.07 rows=118 width=4)"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=83.89..85.07 rows=118 width=4)"
"              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=45.27..83.60 rows=118 width=4)"
"                    Hash Cond: (emp_proj.project_id = p.project_id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on emp_proj  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=45.13..45.13 rows=11 width=4)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..45.13 rows=11 width=4)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using employee_pkey on employee e  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                      Index Cond: (employee_id = 123)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on emp_proj p  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=11 width=8)"
"                                      Filter: (p.employee_id = 123)"
```

Execution Plan of Approach 2:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=60.61..112.29 rows=118 width=98)"
"  ->  Index Scan using employee_pkey on employee e  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4)"
"        Index Cond: (employee_id = 123)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=60.61..102.84 rows=118 width=102)"
"        Hash Cond: (b.employee_id = c.employee_id)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=36.89..77.49 rows=118 width=8)"
"              Hash Cond: (b.project_id = p.project_id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on emp_proj b  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=36.75..36.75 rows=11 width=8)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on emp_proj p  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=11 width=8)"
"                          Filter: (employee_id = 123)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=16.10..16.10 rows=610 width=102)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on employee c  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=610 width=102)"
```

So looks like the Execution plan of Approach 2 is slightly better, because the 'cost' is 60 as opposed to 85 of approach 1. Is that the right way to analyze this?

How does one know it will hold true even for all sorts of many-many combinations?

Comment: The approach that executes faster by looking at the execution plan of the 2 alternatives.

Comment: yeah, I know, but I can never understand the execution plan.

Comment: post the execution plan here; that's the most helpful info if you want to identify your bottlenecks

Comment: @Icarus I updated the description with Query plans. Not really sure how to interpret it.

Comment: What's the DBMS? Is this an execution plan or an explain plan?

Comment: :) If it was a homework question.. I am sure any answer would've been correct.  I use these tables since many years for running my basic tests.

Comment: @eaolson   this is postgres. I used explain plan. lemme check for execution plan.

Comment: @eaolson looks like postgres doesn't have exec plan.. only explain plan.

Comment: I don't know about Postgres, but in Oracle, you absolutely can not compare the cost of two explain plans.

Comment: The Postgres command you want is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which shows both the plan estimate and actual time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both approaches *may* cause sub-optimum performance as they both use subqueries which are optimized efficiently or not depending on the DBMS.

I would suggest to avoid subqueries and use `JOIN` for what is is meant to be used, like:

Edit:

I corrected and simplyfied my example:

```
select coll.EMP_NAME
from EMP_PROJ ep1
inner join EMP_PROJ ep2 on ep1.PROJECT_ID = ep2.PROJECT_ID
inner join EMPLOYEE coll on ep2.EMPLOYEE_ID = coll.EMPLOYEE_ID
where ep1.EMPLOYEE_ID = 123
```

I think one should note that is is perfectly legal to refer to *the same* table more than once with *different* aliases in one query. To the query this logically "looks" like two separate tables which happen to have the same structure and data.

Comment: The OP should also make sure there is an index on `EMP_PROJ.PROJECT_ID`.

Comment: I got a sql error with this query. I retried with:
                      
`inner join EMPLOYEE coll on ep.EMPLOYEE_ID = coll.EMPLOYEE_ID`


But that gave incorrect result: It should me only given employee's name.  

But what I want is:  All Employees of All the Projects that the given Employee belongs to.

Comment: @Hanno Binder  I have tried joins like these, without using subqueries, all seem to restrict me to result that are specific for given employee ID. The only way I have so far been able to get correct result, is if I fetch the Project IDs of given Employee, in a separate sub-query.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I just now realized I don't have  an Index for EMP_PROJ_PROJECT_ID, so thanks for that.

Comment: @rk2010 You wrote "Given an EmployeeID, find ALL the...", so I assumed you just wanted to do that. Could you please clarify what you really want to do?

Comment: @HannoBinder I don't know how else to say this "Problem: Given an EmployeeID, find ALL the employees of ALL Projects that this Employee is associated with."

Any input is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @HannoBinder I think another way to put will be:  "Find project mates of given Employee, across all Projects that the given Employee is associated with"

Comment: @HannoBinder I tried ur latest edit. Looks like that is the way to go. Joining table to itself.. I hadn't thought of it. thank you!